# output a variable in rails containing html code Ruby on Rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, output

I have a little problem with an output in ruby and rails.
I am still a beginner at rails, so it can be that the solution is pretty easy and i just can't see it.

I am trying to parse a website and put out some of the sourcecode on my own website. 
Problem: it always puts out the whole source code as a text and is not interpreting the html code. how can i change that?

code:

```
page = Nokogiri::HTML(open("https://www.google.ch/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=google&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&redir_esc=&ei=WMpyUfSWEuz07AaTioCwDw"))     

source = page.css('div#_css0')

<%=  page %>
```

result:

http://postimg.org/image/dsaib9lx3/

I want to it to look like:

http://postimg.org/image/z9qlhoef5/

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: so what do you want? question is not clear

Comment: @rubyLovely Hope i made it clear

Answer (score 3):

You should use `raw` in erb. It is actually equivalent to calling html_safe on it, but, just like h, is declared on a helper, so it can only be used on controllers and views.

```
page = Nokogiri::HTML(open("https://www.google.ch"))
<%= raw page %>
```

or

```
<%= raw Nokogiri::HTML(open("http://www.google.com")) %>
```

Answer (score 2):

In Rails views every string content gets escaped, unless you use `html_safe` ([docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/String.html#method-i-html_safe))